# Using Timer.schedule to make java program run at a specific time Not working

Tags: java, timertask

I am trying to get use Timer.schedule() to make a task run automatically at a certain time. However, it is not working.
my code:

1. I tried to set up a timer task first
2. I then tried to create a Date object using the current time
3. I then use Timer.schedule(timertask, date) to tell the computer when to do the task.
   However, the timertask doesn't start at the specified date.
   Please help, thank you.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Starts");
                BookingPage page = new BookingPage();
                page.logIn();
                page.selectCourseAndTime();
                page.finishSelectTime();
            }
        };
        Date date = generateDate();
        timer.schedule(task, date);
    }

    public static Date generateDate() {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        String[] arr = dtf.format(now).split("/");
        int[] currentTime = new int[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < currentTime.length; i++) {
            currentTime[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
        }

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(currentTime[0], currentTime[1], currentTime[2], 15, 24, 0);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();

        return date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
month needs to be one less than the current month. For example, May is 4.
problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves the problem

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Timer task started at:"+new Date());
    completeTask();
    System.out.println("Timer task finished at:"+new Date());
}

private void completeTask() {
    try {
        //assuming it takes 20 secs to complete the task
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    TimerTask timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
    //running timer task as daemon thread
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 10*1000);
    System.out.println("TimerTask started");
    //cancel after sometime
    try {
        Thread.sleep(120000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    timer.cancel();
    System.out.println("TimerTask cancelled");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```